# jQuery: Sortable nested list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, hierarchical-data

i'm building a website which has a parent-child Paging structure. I'm looking for a convenient way to administrate the website structure.

- I want the pages to be **sortable**

Releasing the jQuery sortable code on my generated sitemap (nested UL), doesn't work properly...

```
$('ul.SiteMap ul').sortable();
```

What's really important is that it should **not** be possible to sort outside of the current UL. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me. I just assigned each ul to be sorted to a class and then did the following:

```
$('.sortableList').sortable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
items: 'ul > li'
```

?

You have to list all ULs, though:

```
$('ul.SiteMap ul, ul.sitemap ul ul, ul.sitemap ul ul ul').sortable({
items: 'ul > li'
});
```

I am a beginner, so there is perhaps a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Changing order of children within a parent is easy just give each ul a class '.sort' and do $('.sort').sortable();

I gets a little trickier when changing the parent.