# Sorting an li element in a sortable list with few levels?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Maybe i've built it all wrong, but this is how my lists are built:

```
<ul class="chapters">
    <li class="chapter-content">chapter 1</li>
    <li class="chapter-article-container">
        <ul class="articles">
            <li class="article-content">Article 1</li>
            <li class="article-content">Article 2</li>
            <li class="article-content">Article 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="chapter-content">chapter 2</li>
    <li class="chapter-article-container">
        <ul class="articles">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="chapter-content">chapter 3</li>
    <li class="chapter-article-container">
        <ul class="articles">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wish to sort the chapters around carrying the articles alongs.
If i move chapter 1 beneath chapter 3, i want chapter 1 articles to move along.
How can i do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you won't simply put your articles UL inside of chapter-content LI and than use that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2915167/2028547 ?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Xj27q/ ?

Comment: Well, mostly because my <li class="chapter-content"> is a simplified version of my li which contain css design, left and right buttons bars and fields of text. Adding the <ul class="articles"> inside the li, on one side works, on the other it messes up all the design and i'll have to rebuilt everything. 
I guess that is my only option, changing the design from the li to a div and adding the ul articles element inside the chapter li.
Anyway, thanks for the guide lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the html so chapter one contains the articles like this

```
  <li class="chapter-article-container">
        Chapter 1
        <ul class="articles">
            <li class="article-content">Article 1</li>
            <li class="article-content">Article 2</li>
            <li class="article-content">Article 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4u9M/2/)

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit difficult solution mainly because my <li class="chapter-content"> is a simplified version of my li which contain css design, left and right buttons bars and fields of text. Adding the <ul class="articles"> inside the li, on one side works, on the other it messes up all the design and i'll have to rebuilt everything. I guess that is my only option, changing the design from the li to a div and adding the ul articles element inside the chapter li. Anyway, thanks for the guide lines.